# Boot a program that would choose a particular Ubuntu iso and boot from it

Tags: c++, c, assembly, boot

I want to create a program that I would load on an external hard drive such that it a computer could boot from it. The basics of this program would be to list some Ubuntu LiveCD. Then, the user would select a LiveCD and I would then boot the chosen LiveCD.

What I want to know is how can I boot a c or c++ program that would list (probably from a text file) the different versions available. I know how to do that in c++ (pretty simple). However, what I don't know is how to boot this program. What kind of assembly code could I use to launch such a program?

Are there any books or tutorial that I could read about this topic?

Comment: "boot"? As in, start the computer up and run this program (unlikely), or "run" instead? Are you asking about getting the list of versions from a text file or web server? Please _please_ be more specific.

Comment: I mean boot as in starting the computer since I would boot a live cd. I'm asking how could I boot a c++ program.

Comment: You should start with a generic bootloader and exploit their capabilities. Grub2 is extremly powerful and allows direct booting from ISO-images. For my own use i've created an USB Bootstick based on sysresccd (sysresccd.org/) which also has a couple of common installer-images on it which i've added to the boot menu, works like a charm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking is incredibly hard. You are asking how to write a [boot loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Boot_loader), which is a very complex thing to do. You will need to handle video output, mouse/keyboard, usb drivers, mounting disks, etc, etc - you are writing a mini-OS in fact.

For tips/examples take a look at [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/).

---

You might "cheat" and use an existing boot loader to load a tiny linux kernel from which you can use C to boot the ISO, but this still is very hard thing to do. I would suggest looking into alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if I had to make a boot loader for this. I'll start digging into that ! Thanks

Comment: Incredibly hard is an understatement! ;)

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/iso-boot-loader-for-cd-dvd-656785/ this pretty much explains what I want to do.